# Web service with maven and glassfish

Tags: eclipse, maven, glassfish, java-ee-6

I've created a web service with maven, compiled it and deployed it on a glassfish server. My question is : how to access that web service ?
What I've done so far :

- Complie the project with mvn package -> build success
- Start the glassfish server -> check, localhost:8080 is ok, server is started
- Deploy the application : asadmin deploy myapp.war -> that's ok, I can see it when typing asadmin list-components

What i'd like to do is access to the web service... because when I type localhost:8080/myapp/, i've got a 404 error. 
Do I have to create a web.xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

What does "access" mean to you?

In the context of web services, it usually means requesting the WSDL so either your client or something like SOAP UI can formulate a proper request to POST and get a response back.

Comment: Indeed, before to switch to maven project and glassfish, I did it with tomcat. In that former version, I access the web service that way in my client : String sampleURL = SERVICE_URL + "/sample";
        WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.GET_TASK, this, "Getting data...");
        wst.execute(new String[] { sampleURL });. But now, I've got a 404 error returning.

Comment: OK, so you know how to do this.  What does 404 mean?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404.  The server can't find what you're asking for.  URL problems....or you didn't deploy it correctly.  YOu either didn't deploy it the same as Tomcat, or Glassfish needs something else, or you asked for it incorrectly.  Leave Maven out of it until you get it right.

Comment: But my deployement seems to be ok. Of course I know what 404 means, but I'd like to know what goes wrong. I didn't deployes it on glassfish the same way as tomcat. But should I create a web.xml to explicit the path the request the web service ? And if so, what to put in it ?

Comment: "Seems to be okay" - I would suggest that you should assume that it's not until you figure this out.

Comment: I say such a thing because I see the project in the asadmin list-components. I know that it doesn't mean that everything is fine but that's a first step isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was somewhere else. I've forgotten to create the file extending application that was the "entrence" of the weh service (something like that :

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath( "/restapi" )
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {}
```

). So now the problem is solved and I get informations from the web service that way

```
localhost:8080/myapp/restapi/
```